# while swiping the animal portion images it give error [Error message]:Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException))

Tags: android

> when i swipe images of animal or car,it give me error as i swipe from 3rd image to 4th image ,error is of arrayindexoutofboundexception ,i have seen tutorials but didnot find any specific answer related to my problem.I have posted in stackoverflow for the very first time so please try to understand my question ,your help would be appreciated thankyou

//Activity class which contain viewpager
 package com.example.image;

```
public class LikeMainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
ViewPager vp;
fragment1 f;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_like_main);
    vp=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

    f=new fragment1(getApplicationContext());
    vp.setCurrentItem(1);
    vp.setAdapter(f);
    }
```

//class named as fragment extends pager adapter

```
public class fragment1 extends PagerAdapter {
Context ctx;
LayoutInflater lytifltr;
private int[] bike = { R.drawable.bike, R.drawable.bike1, R.drawable.bike2, R.drawable.bike3, R.drawable.bike4,
        R.drawable.bike5 };
private int[] car = { R.drawable.car, R.drawable.car1, R.drawable.car2, R.drawable.car3 };
private int[] animal = { R.drawable.animal, R.drawable.animal1, R.drawable.animal2, R.drawable.animal3 };
private int[] flower = { R.drawable.flower, R.drawable.flower1, R.drawable.flower2, R.drawable.flower3,
        R.drawable.flower4 };
member m = new member();

public fragment1(Context ctx) {
    Intent i = new Intent();
    this.ctx = ctx;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return bike.length;
}

String abc = "";

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    return (arg0 == (LinearLayout) arg1);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    lytifltr = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View itemview = lytifltr.inflate(R.layout.imageswipe, container, false);
    ImageView img = (ImageView) itemview.findViewById(R.id.imageVew1);
    abc = m.type.toString();
    if (m.type == "car") {
        img.setImageResource(car[position]);
    } else if (m.type == "flower") {
        img.setImageResource(flower[position]);
    } else if (m.type == "bike") {
        img.setImageResource(bike[position]);
    } else if (m.type == "animal") {

            img.setImageResource(animal[position]);

        }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(ctx, "Nothing", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    container.addView(itemview);
    return itemview;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    container.removeView((LinearLayout) object);

}

@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.getItemPosition(object);
}
```

}

Comment: Worth a read, IMHO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Comment: @Talha please change "==" by .equalsIgnoreCase() as "==" will yield to incorrect results.

Answer (score 1):

The crash is because you are returning `bike.length` from `getCount()`

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return bike.length;
}
```

But  accessing invalid index from `instantiateItem()`. (NB: I did **fix** your code to use `equals()` to compare strings, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) for more explanations)

```
if ("car".equals(m.type)) {
    img.setImageResource(car[position]);
} else if ("flower".equals(m.type)) {
    img.setImageResource(flower[position]);
} else if ("bike".equals(m.type)) {
    img.setImageResource(bike[position]);
} else if ("animal".equals(m.type)) {
    img.setImageResource(animal[position]);
}
```

The number of items in `bike`,`car`, `animal`, `flower` array are different:

```
private int[] bike = { R.drawable.bike, R.drawable.bike1, R.drawable.bike2, R.drawable.bike3, R.drawable.bike4,
        R.drawable.bike5 }; //Total 6
private int[] car = { R.drawable.car, R.drawable.car1, R.drawable.car2, R.drawable.car3 }; //Total 4
private int[] animal = { R.drawable.animal, R.drawable.animal1, R.drawable.animal2, R.drawable.animal3 }; //Total 4
private int[] flower = { R.drawable.flower, R.drawable.flower1, R.drawable.flower2, R.drawable.flower3,
        R.drawable.flower4 }; //Total 5
```

And hence when you try to access lets say `5th` page, and number of elements in animal array is only `4`, you get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException`

### Solution:

You have to make all the arrays contain equal number of elements or in `getCount()` return that array length which has minimum number of elements

Comment: @RC That is not my code . It is shared by Talha . Please see the question. Anyways nice catch.

Comment: Shadab Ansari Thanks alot :-)  i wish i could rate your answer :)